# Center Bootstrap Button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, center

I'm having trouble with centering Bootstrap button in panel. Margin right and left auto doesn't work.
Is there a way to properly center the button? The Button needs to be centered because of the mobile scale.

[image]

Code:

```
<div class="n_monitor">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="btn-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Server 1</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="caret"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.n_monitor .panel {
    width: 628px;
    border: solid 1px #ebebeb;
    border-top-left-radius: 0px;
    border-top-right-radius: 0px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
    height: 94px;
    box-shadow: none;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.n_monitor .btn {
    width: 126px;
    height: 54px;
    background-color: #3baed8;
    border: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 14px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add Bootstrap's [Alignment Class](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#type-alignment) `text-center` to `.panel-body`.

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');

.n_monitor .panel {
  width: 100%;
  border: solid 1px #ebebeb;
  border-top-left-radius: 0px;
  border-top-right-radius: 0px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
  height: 94px;
  box-shadow: none;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.n_monitor .btn {
  width: 126px;
  height: 54px;
  background-color: #3baed8;
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="n_monitor">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body text-center">
        <div class="btn-group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Server 1</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="caret"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
          </button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
          </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Without you I would be in so much pain.
Take a Cookie. <3

Answer (score 2):

You can simply add "center-block" class to the button.

e.g.

```
<button class = "center-block">Test</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

This always works the best for me. Particularity when using Bootstrap it works perfectly.

```
#button{
display: table; margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Center the text on the button's parent (.n_monitor .panel-body)

```
.n_monitor .panel-body
{
    text-align: center;
}
```